# Function call from code behind

Tags: c#, jquery

How to i calling jQuery function from code behind after button click...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".chkOther").change(function () {
            //console.log($(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked"));
            if (!$(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked")) {
                $(this).closest(".frome_group").find(".cleartxt").val("");
                //$(this).closest(".frome_group").find(".cleartxt").attr('readonly',true);
            }
            else {
                //$(this).closest(".frome_group").find(".cleartxt").removeAttr('readonly');
                $(this).closest(".frome_group").find(".cleartxt").focus();
            }
        });

        function successMessage() {
            $("#successModal").modal('show');
        }

        function errorMessage() {
            $("#errorModal").modal('show');
        }
    });
</script>
```

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "successMessage", "successMessage();", true);
```

Comment: Thank you Rory McCrossan from Gide me how to put post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Problem with your question**

You are asking, how to call a javascript action after button click. But additionally, you want to call it from code behind? Why do you not call it after clicking your button?

Please be sure to understand the HTTP client-server architecture before asking such questions.

**Maybe you mean this?**

Since you didn't specify the result you are aiming for, I have to assume that you want to call `successMessage()` or `errorMessage()` after finishing a Server request. You would do something like this using [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/API/Controller/Method",
  success: function () {
    successMessage();
  },
  error: function () {
    errorMessage();
  }
});
```

Comment: @Wolle protected void lnkSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (flag == true)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "successMessage", "successMessage();", true);
        }
        else
        {
           ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "errorMessage", "errorMessage();", true);
       }
    }